# Как исключить элемент из массива в JS?

Tags: javascript

Есть такой скрипт

```
(function () {
  var spoilers = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.spoiler-wrap,.sp-wrap,.sp-head'));
  if (!spoilers.length) {
    return;
  }
  var btn = document.createElement('button');
  btn.type = 'button';
  btn.innerHTML = 'Открыть все спойлеры';
  btn.addEventListener('click', function () {
    spoilers.forEach(function (node) {
      node.querySelector('.clickable').dispatchEvent(new Event('click'));
    });
  });
  spoilers[0].insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin', '<br>');
  spoilers[0].insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin', '&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp');
  spoilers[0].parentNode.insertBefore(btn, spoilers[0]);
})();
```

открывающий все спойлеры на странице. Можно ли сделать так, чтобы открывались все, кроме тех (их два), которые не нужно открывать?

Разметка не нужных:

```
td.row1 table[id^="post_"] style+table.btTbl div.center .spoiler-wrap
```

Нужные спойлеры имеют такую разметку

```
tr.row2 td.row2 table[id^="post_"] div.postbody .spoiler-wrap
```

В полной версии ненужные спойлеры "Список файлов в торренте" и "Похожие темы"
[Полная версия](https://pastebin.com/3gxxkWfE)

Разметка ненужных спойлеров в оригинале

```
<div align="center">
  <div class="spoiler-wrap" style="width: 95%; margin: 6px auto; clear: both; border: solid #6699CC; background: #D0DFEF; border-width: 1px 1px 1px 2px;" onmousedown="var d=document.getElementById('contentdiv');if(!d.flDone){ajax_do('filelst.php?attach_id=757422');}"
    align="center">
    <div class="spoiler-head folded clickable">Список файлов в торренте</div>
    <div class="spoiler-body" id="contentdiv" style="border-top:1px solid #6699CC; background: #F4F8FB; padding: 1px 6px 2px; display: none;overflow:auto;max-height:350px;" title="">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="simil"></div>
<div align="center">
  <div class="spoiler-wrap" style="width: 95%; margin: 6px auto; clear: both; border: solid #6699CC; background: #D0DFEF; border-width: 1px 1px 1px 2px; font-weight: bold;" align="center">
    <div class="spoiler-head folded clickable">Похожие темы (2992 совп.; «k, авторск, раздач»):</div>
    <div class="sim spoiler-body" style="border-top:1px solid #6699CC; background: #F4F8FB; padding: 1px 6px 2px; display: none;" title="">
```

Comment: Видимо вам надо добаывить условие в `spoilers.forEach`, но не понятно какое, так как вы не привели этого условия. То есть не понятно, как отследить "те два". Уточните ваш вопрос.

Comment: _Можно ли сделать так, чтобы открывались все, кроме тех (их два), которые не нужно открывать?_ - да, так сделать можно.

Comment: @Grundy , как это сделать?

Comment: @БлагоѨръТишина̀, нужно просто проверить, что текущий элемент не один из тех.

Comment: @Grundy, я не силён в JS. Скрипт писал парень JavaScript.Ru. Если не трудно, то опиши, как эту проверку сделать?

Comment: @БлагоѨръТишина̀, для этого ты должен добавить в вопрос, как минимум описание того, как определять какие элементы показывать, а какие нет

Comment: @Grundy, сейчас правильно?

Comment: Уже лучше.  И добавь еще минимальный пример разметки где будут и те которые нужно открывать и те, которые не нужно.

Comment: Под разметкой имелся ввиду пример html.

Comment: @Grundy теперь правильно?

Answer (score 2):

Простое решение, просто не добавлять ненужные элементы в выборку.

Например расширив селектор: `document.querySelectorAll('div.postbody .spoiler-wrap,.sp-wrap,.sp-head')`

В этом случае ненужные элементы не будут находиться в коллекции.

Альтернативным решением может быть проверка родителя непосредственно в цикле.

Родительский элемент можно получить с помощью свойства [`parentNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Node/parentNode).

Таким образом вызывать `click` нужно только есть у родителя нет класса `center`. Проверить это можно, вызвав [метод `contains` у свойства `classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)

```
spoilers.forEach(function (node) {
  if(node.parentNode.classList.contains('center')) return;
  node.querySelector('.clickable').dispatchEvent(new Event('click'));
});
```

Comment: По классу center не прокатит, так как и нужные и ненужные его имеют.
А вот этот "div.postbody .spoiler-wrap" подойдёт. А куда вставить расширенный селектор (уж извиняюсь за вопрос)?

Comment: @БлагоѨръТишина̀, там где ты список получаешь `var spoilers = [].slice.call(...`

Comment: спасибо, всё работает.

Comment: @БлагоѨръТишина̀, можешь отметить ответ галочкой